# VBA macro to insert image from URL in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, macros, powerpoint

can I please get some help with writing a VBA macro in PPT that will perform the following two tasks:

1. Insert a new slide (Title and Content format)
2. Insert an image (in SVG format) from a URL into content area. The URL has a number of query string parameters that renders a "svg" image.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't accept SVG graphics, so the rest of the question is moot.

Comment: Thanks @steve-rindsberg. Do you know if it's possible to convert SVG graphics to PNG using VBA and then insert the PNG graphic?

Comment: You can't directly convert SVG in VBA (unless you want to write a transcoder from scratch!) but you could Shell a conversation command from VBA to an external converter such as ImageMagick (which I've done before).

Comment: Thanks @jamieg. Would you mind sharing your VBA script? Also, does this mean that if I were to share the Macro enabled PPT files with others, they would need to have ImageMagick installed on their machines for this to work?

Comment: @Raj Yes, in order for a script that calls on ImageMagick to work, it'd have to have a copy of Image Magick to work on. But have a look here:  http://www.imagemagick.org/script/ImageMagickObject.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below for a stripped down VBA example for processing an image file via ImageMagick V6 (V7 changes the **convert** command to **magick**). This is a very simple command example. There are hundreds of parameters for ImageMagick and you'll need to find the ones you need for your image processing operation from [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/)

```
' ***********************************************************************************
' Purpose : Convert an image file from one format to another using ImageMagick
' Dependencies : Requires ImageMagic DLL package for Windows (V6) to be pre-installed
' Author  : Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd. (http://youpresent.co.uk/)
' ***********************************************************************************
Public Sub TestImageMagic()
  Dim sCmd As String
  Dim retval As Variant
  Const ImgIn = "C:\Temp\ImageIn.svg"
  Const ImgOut = "C:\Temp\ImageOut.png"
  Const QUOT = """"
  ' Construct the ImageMagick command line in the format:
  ' "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\convert" "C:\Temp\ImageIn.svg" "C:\Temp\ImageOut.png"
  sCmd = QUOT & GetInstallPathIM & "\" & "convert" & QUOT & _
         " " & QUOT & ImgIn & QUOT & _
         " " & QUOT & ImgOut & QUOT
  On Error Resume Next
  ' Process the image with ImageMagic
  If Len(sCmd) <= 8192 Then retval = oShell.Run(sCmd, 0, True)
  If retval <> 0 Or Err <> 0 Then
    ' Manage errors
  End If
  On Error Goto 0
End Sub

' ***********************************************************************************
' Purpose : Function to return the installation path for ImageMagic
'           from the Windows Environment Path string.
' Author  : Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd. (http://youpresent.co.uk/)
' ***********************************************************************************
Private Function GetImageMagickPath() As String
  Dim WinPath As String ' Windows Environment Path string
  Dim IM As Integer ' Position of the start of ImageMagic string
  Dim PathStart As Integer ' Position of first left semi-colon of the ImageMagic string
  Dim PathEnd As Integer ' Position of right semi-colon of the ImageMagic string

  ' Get the Windows Environment Path string
  WinPath = Environ("PATH")
  ' Parse out the ImageMagick path by looking for ImageMagick and then searching back and forwards to the previous and next occurrence of ";"
  IM = InStr(1, WinPath, "ImageMagick")
  If IM > 0 Then
    PathStart = InStrRev(WinPath, ";", IM) + 1
    PathEnd = InStr(IM, WinPath, ";")
    GetImageMagickPath = Mid(WinPath, PathStart, PathEnd - PathStart)
  Else
    MsgBox "ImageMagick components aren't installed!"
  End If
End Function
```